# How can we create zend light framework [for api]

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Zend is an amazing framework, I don't need an MVC for my API development, just need Model and Controller. the return value will be JSON data format. How can I remove the extra feature in the Zend skeleton?

Comment: Hi, i would recommend you to use Apigility(https://apigility.org/). It is build with Zend Framework specially for building high-quality APIs. It has great features like RESTful or RPC services; JSON (specifically, HAL); Problem Details for HTTP APIs; Versioning; Normalisation and Validation; Authentication (HTTP Basic/Digest, OAuth2); Documentation (HTML, Swagger, API Blueprint..

Comment: Apigility is UI based right? I need lust like lumen.

Comment: No, Apigility by default comes with a few packages installed (`require-dev` in `composer.json`) which install an Admin UI. If you're deploying on production you would run `composer install --no-dev` to ensure development packages are not included. The provided UI is only to be used to help with development. There's no UI for production. If you need some form of management UI for managing data/users/etc, then you should create one which uses your Apigility setup as it's data store.

Comment: Don't forget to enable development mode (in ZF as well as Apigility) by running `composer development-enable`